# strsplit by variable separator

Tags: r, strsplit

I have some strings of data separated by " " that needs to be split into columns. Is there an easy way to split the data by every nth separator. For example, the first value in x tells you that the first 4 values in y correspond to the first trial. The second value in x tells you that the next 3 values in y correspond to the second trial, and so on.

```
x <- c("4 3 3", "3 3 3 2 3")
y <- c("110 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 33 44 11 22 11", "44 55 66 33 22 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 66 77 88")
```

The goal is something like this:

```
structure(list(session = 1:2, trial.1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("110 88 77", 
"44 55 66"), class = "factor"), trial.2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("33 22 11", 
"66 55 44"), class = "factor"), trial.3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("22 33 44", 
"23 33 44"), class = "factor"), trial.4 = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "55 66", class = "factor"), 
    trial.5 = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "77 88 66", class = "factor")), .Names = c("session", 
"trial.1", "trial.2", "trial.3", "trial.4", "trial.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Ideally, any extra values from y need to be dropped from the resulting data frame, and the uneven row lengths should be filled with NA's.

Comment: `strsplit(y, " ")` then use x as a selector of elements in the resultant structure, then add your own spaces back in.

Comment: Do you mean do it manually? I should have mentioned this is a simplified version of my real data.

Comment: Your structure statement seems odd to me, do you have a particular R routine that you want to run after this cleaning, if you don't I'd suggest a vastly different structure than you are suggesting.

Comment: @Seth I'm planning on reshaping the data using the reshape package after and THEN splitting individual cases by " ". Any suggestions or approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe useful

```
dumx<-strsplit(x,' ')
dumy<-strsplit(y,' ')
dumx<-lapply(dumx,function(x)(cumsum(as.numeric(x))))
dumx<-lapply(dumx,function(x){mapply(seq,c(1,x+1)[-(length(x)+1)],x,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)})
ans<-mapply(function(x,y){lapply(x,function(w,z){z[w]},z=y)},dumx,dumy)
```

I will leave you to convert the resulting list to dataframe :)

Comment: Any reason why this code wouldn't work when the every value in dumx is the same?

Comment: aah, I see. I should familiarize myself with mapply better